# I get product based on price filter on two column like above code. can I do with other short code or short this code and any laravel inbuilt function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, shortcode

I get product based on a price filter on two columns like the above code.

can I do with other shortcode or short this code

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::query()
        ->where('status', '1')
        ->when($request->range, fn ($query) => $query->whereBetween('actual_price', [0, 1600]))
        ->when($request->range, fn ($query) => $query->orWhereBetween('saleable_price', [0, 1600]))
        ->orderBy('saleable_price', 'asc')->get();
    return view('frontend.product.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptions, before you add tags to your question! `shortcode` is specifically for WordPress shortcode functionality, which your question is not about at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put both your range queries into one callback

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::query()
        ->where('status', '1')
        ->when($request->range, function ($query) { 
           $query->whereBetween('actual_price', [0, 1600])
              ->orWhereBetween('saleable_price', [0, 1600]);
        })
        ->orderBy('saleable_price', 'asc')->get();
    return view('frontend.product.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: Yes we can do it. Thanx